# When are Support (v4, v7)'s Android libraries required

Tags: android, android-activity, version

Hi Android newbiew but not programming newbie, I'm making an app with the following:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 25
```

I'm reading the developer guide and I come across things like this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.A...
```

or

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity...
```

But `ActivityCompat` comes from `android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat` and `AppCompatActivity` comes from `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`
which is from the v4/v7 library, this seems inconsistent - we are importing a library designed to support functionality back to v4 to do something that was implemented in 23? Is this just something Android does or is there something else going on here?

My code works but I don't fully understand why - also, going forwards, do I need any support libraries at all?

Comment: Even if you only develop for API 25 (minSdkVersion of 25), you'll always want to use the appropriate support libraries (there are a lot of them) as that is the best way to build an app that is consistent on all API levels.

Comment: "we are importing a library designed to support functionality back to v4 to do something that was implemented in 23?" -- sure. For example, your `minSdkVersion` is 19. `requestPermissions` on *`Activity`* was added in API Level 23. 19 < 23. You cannot call `requestPermissions()` on `Activity` on devices running Android 4.4/5.0/5.1; if you try, you will crash. You can either check the device's API level and do your own workaround, or you can use the supplied workaround baked into `ActivityCompat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ActionBar to your activity when running on API level 7 or higher by extending AppCompatActivity for your activity and setting the activity theme to Theme.AppCompat or a similar theme.
More ：
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html

Comment: I'm not asking about `ActionBar` or is there some significance to it?